# wso2ei 7 ballerina to sign a soap request

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ballerina

We are using wso2ei 6.4.0 for SOAP and REST service mediation, some services are required to sign the requests or validate the message signature.

Deploying to Kubernetes I'm considering to migrate to WSO2EI 7 (which is Ballerina based), however at this point I am unable to find out how to secure (sign or validate) the SOAP payload.

At this point the only option I see is implementing the signing on my own (by XML manipulation or custom Java code).

Is it really so or do we have any other (robust, out of box) options to enforce  WS-Policy requirements?

Edit:

I found the [wso2/soap](https://central.ballerina.io/wso2/soap) module, which only supports UsernameToken (password and digest), which is already basic, but apparently we will need to extend it :(

Comment: At this point the most feasible workaround is to build a small SpringBoot or nodejs service to validate the request or sign the payload